# Firebase Authentication SMS Quota exceeded for this project

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, sms, one-time-password

After running for 2 years without hitting any quota limits, My app is hitting a daily quota limit on login (firebase phone authentication) which is not allowing any users to use the app and saying "SMS Quota for this project has been exceeded".
I checked firebase auth usage and its far way from the free tier limit(10K), and also it's on Blaze pay as you go plan.
I also checked Google Cloud Platform quotas page and it shows that all quota are within limit..
GCP support replied the following:
"Cloud Functions quotas are all within limits, the quota exceeded messages are coming from another system."

Any idea haw can this be solved?!

Comment: 10k is limit for 1 month , daily free otp limit is 357 please check if daily otp are exceeding free limit . Go to firebase console > open settings > open usage and billing  check your daily limit. And as you mentioned your project is on blaze plan after 357 limit firebase will charge you for every OTP . please also check if your billing info is up to date ?

Comment: even though i have selected Blaza plan and my payment info are good i am getting same exceeded limit error message. i have appiled temp quota , let me see after an hour if its increasing .

Answer (score 5):

### From now on firebase new projects currently have an SMS daily quota of 50 / day.

---

You can see: firebase console > Authentication > sign-in method

[image]

if daily sms are exceeding limit
go to : firebase console > open settings > open usage and billing check your daily limit.

Comment: Hi, do you have any idea how long is a project considered "new"?

Comment: @Yogesch no idea

Comment: @Yogesch I don't think the word "New" here is relative to time but instead in relative to existing projects. It could possibly meaning that your existing projects won't be affected by this limit but your newly created ones will.

If you want to link a billing account to the project to overcome this limit. Follow this instruction by Google Cloud (https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#confirm_billing_is_enabled_on_a_project)

Answer (score 0):

**Firebase Identity platform daily limit is 10sms/day**

Im using Identity platform in my project

[image]

You will find details info about it in the below link

[Firebase phone auth daily limit info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits#phone-auth)

Answer (score 0):

**As of Jan 2024**

> Note: The limits for email link sign-in emails were recently changed. Please add a billing instrument to go beyond 5 email link sign-in emails.

If you are using Email link for sign-in and authentication then you will need to **upgrade to Blaze plan** as stated firebase [website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits#email_sending_limits)