# FirebaseAuth SMS verification code request failed

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I don't know what does this error mean. I've search a lot on Google, but couldn't find why am I getting this error.

```
E/FirebaseAuth( 5673): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17052 Exceeded quota.
```

I'm trying to authenticate android client with firebase phone auth sign-in method, and trying to verify their phone number by sending a verification code on their phone. No code is being sent and no callback function is called. I don't know what is the problem here
and i enable the Phone Sign-in method in your firebase
Android Device Verification is enable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase limits daily SMS allowed to prevent abuse. You can refer to this other thread [Firebase Authentication SMS Quota exceeded for this project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66606388/firebase-authentication-sms-quota-exceeded-for-this-project)